# Cannot read properties of undefined react router on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-router

I am making a recipe app by using Edamam recipe API.Every thing is working fine until I refresh Recipe Detail page.when I open a recipe it works fine but when I refresh page for example `http://localhost:3000/recipe/Pasta%20alla%20Gricia%20Recipe` it gives me an error :

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'recipe')`

I dont know why is this happening.It is working when the page is not refreshed.

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import ShowRecipe from "./pages/ShowRecipe";
import RecipeDetail from "./pages/RecipeDetail.js";
import {
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function App(){
  return(
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/recipe">Recipe</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/recipe" element={<ShowRecipe />} />
        <Route path="/recipe/:recipeId" element={<RecipeDetail />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

ShowRecipe.js:

```
import React,{useContext,useState,useEffect} from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {Context} from "../Context"

function ShowRecipe(){

  const {recipes,getSearch,search,handleChange} = useContext(Context)

     let dispRecipe = recipes.map(recipe => (
           <div>
             <img src={recipe.recipe.image} />
            <Link to={`/recipe/${recipe.recipe.label}`}><h1>{recipe.recipe.label}</h1></Link>
             <p>{recipe.recipe.calories}</p>
           </div>
         ))

  return(
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={getSearch}>
        <input type="text" value={search} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>

       {dispRecipe}

    </div>
  )
}

export default ShowRecipe;
```

RecipeDetail.js:

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react';
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom"
import {Context} from "../Context"



function RecipeDetail(){

    const {recipes} = useContext(Context)
    const {recipeId} = useParams()

    const currentRecipe = recipes.find(recipe => recipe.recipe.label === recipeId)

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{currentRecipe.recipe.label}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default RecipeDetail
```

Context.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"

const Context = React.createContext()

function  ContextProvider({children}) {
    const API_KEY = "648ac4cc09c9168758cc92c64b18ecfc"
  const API_ID = "854d3ad3"

  const [recipes , setRecipes] = useState([])
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("")
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("pasta")

  let example =`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&from=0&to=20&app_id=${API_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}`

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(example)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
          setRecipes(data.hits);
          console.log(data)
      })
  }, [query])

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value)
    console.log(search)
  }

  const getSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setQuery(search)
  }

  console.log(recipes)

  return (
        <Context.Provider value={{
            recipes,
            search,
            getSearch,
            handleChange,
        }}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )

}

export {ContextProvider, Context}
```

Comment: I think you need to check if `currentRecipe` is defined inside `RecipeDetail`. `currentRecipe` might be `undefined` when the app initially starts (`recipes` is still an empty array `[]`). Something like `currentRecipe ? <h1>{currentRecipe.recipe.label}</h1> : <h1>Recipe not found</h1>`

Comment: @Jackyef it is working now first it says Recipe not found but after 1 sec it displays the recipe. Can you tell how is this is happening.Is this the only way of making it work

Answer (score 1):

On this line you are creating the context for your React application

```
const Context = React.createContext()
```

The argument for the `createContext` call is the initial state--here it is undefined. Because there's no initial state, the value of this context is undefined.

It's not very intuitive, but this initial value is the value that the components in your application will receive during the first render--even if you set `value` in your provider.

```js
console.log(useContext(Context)) // undefined
```

You later attempt to destructure this undefined object

```js
const {recipes,getSearch,search,handleChange} = useContext(Context)
```

Which results in the error "Can not read properties of undefined".

When you move to the page by using react's routing, the context has had enough time to initialise with the value you expect. When you refresh the page, the context hasn't had enough time to initialise with the value you expect. Hence you end up seeing this error.

As one helper already stated, you should check that the value in the context is available before you try to access it. You have multiple options here.

Waiting for the context value to be defined

```
const context = useContext(Context)

if (!context) {
  return "Loading..."
}
```

Setting an initial value in the context

```
const Context = React.createContext({
  recipes: []
})
```

Modeling the loading state in your context

```
const Context = React.createContext({
  recipes: null,
  isLoading: true,
})

// ...

const [isLoadingRecipes , setLoadingRecipes] = useState(true)

// ...

  useEffect(()=>{
    setLoadingRecipes(true)
    fetch(example)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
          setRecipes(data.hits);
          setLoadingRecipes(false);
          console.log(data)
      })
  }, [query])

// ...

const {recipes, isLoading} = useContext(Context)

if (!recipes && isLoading) {
  return "Loading...";
}
```